# Instrument systematically underpredicting endogenous variable based on values of outcome variable

Tags: instrumental-variables

Consider the following linear regression model:
$$
y_{i}=x_{i}\beta+\epsilon_{i}
$$
In the above, the error term is not conditionally mean independent
of $x_{i},$ that is $\mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon_{i}|X_{i}\right)\neq0$.
Consider now, an instrument $z_{i}$ that can be used to identify
$\beta$ by exploiting exogenous variation in $x_{i}$. That is
$$
x_{i}=\gamma z_{i}+v_{i}
$$
 is used to obtain fitted values of $x_{i}$, which are then used
in place of $x_{i}$ in the original regression. The instrument is
plausibly exogenous and is also relevant (i.e. it helps predicts $x_{i}$).
In my study, however, it seems that the instrument systematically
underpredicts $x_{i}$ for higher values of $y_{i.}.$ In other words,
the residual term
$$
x_{i}-\hat{\gamma}z_{i}=\tilde{v_{i}}
$$
 is systematically increasing with $y_{i}$ such that $cov\left(y_{i},\tilde{v_{i}}\right)>0.$
Does this then imply that this instrument is invalid? Can anything
be done to solve the issue if any?

Comment: sounds like the instrument is not appropriately calibrated across the full dynamic range - a linear model for transforming zi to xi worked over a short range of values, but it sounds as if the relationship should be something other than a simple linear trends, maybe a polynomial, exponential or other model that handles increasing slope. Is this based on experience with real data or is it a toy problem? either way please share a concrete example.